# How can I connect APP Engine with Cloud SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, loopbackjs

I created an app with looopback v4. it is deployed on a GCP.
with the following yaml file

```
runtime: nodejs8

env_variables:
  SQL_USER: [REDACTED]
  SQL_PASSWORD: [REDACTED]
  SQL_DATABASE: [REDACTED]
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: [REDACTED]

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: [REDACTED]
```

The datasource json config file for the loopback v4 repository is

```
{
  "name": [REDACTED],
  "connector": "mysql",
  "url": "",
  "host": "ip",
  "port": 3306,
  "user": [REDACTED],
  "password": [REDACTED],
  "database": [REDACTED]
}
```

the datasource and the repository are automatically configured with the CLI of loopback and in local environment on my pc is working ok.

After the deploy I changed the datasource json config file because I know that I cannot use the public IP of the google cloud db so I switched with the connection instance name

```
{
  "name": [REDACTED],
  "connector": "mysql",
  "url": "",
  "host": [REDACTED],
  "port": 3306,
  "user": [REDACTED],
  "password": [REDACTED],
  "database": [REDACTED]
}
```

but it didn't work.  I even use "socketPath" instead of IP (because that was the name in loopback3)

Comment: Why can't you use the public IP? The public IP is meant to be used to connect to the database instance.

Comment: Do not use public IP addressing for security reasons. Your second method using the Cloud SQL Proxy is the correct method. Edit your questions, show your code and the exact error messages.

Comment: We have two way to connect.
1. Use Cloud SQL proxy. 
2. Use public endpoint. 
3. Use Cloud SQL TCP host, like this `':/cloudsql/rappler5-development:asia-east2:wordpress'`. 
Which one are you using on your GAE ?

Comment: Please refrain from sharing sensitive information like passwords, usernames, instance names, etc.